# How can I tell an Google App Engine app to stop itself?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

At a high level: When deployed, I want my Google App Engine app to run through some code and then stop the program automatically once it's finished, so that I don't have to manually stop the versions or instances using the UI.

I tried using the both the stop and delete instances in the Google Compute Engine API here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/delete

When I do that it gives me a successful response with a status equal to 'PENDING.' But when I look at the logs for the app, rather than stopping it looks like it's just repeating the code that I deployed over and over again, which I interpret as, "Oh it must not be stopping the app/instances then."

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to tell a Google App Engine app to stop itself?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems like you want the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/), rather than the Compute Engine API.  I think setting `servingStatus` via [`app.services.versions.patch`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch) is probably what you want, but I'm not sure.